# VBA string array values are always ""

Tags: arrays, vba

I'm trying to create an array of strings. In the watches window, it always says that the value of my array items are "", instead of the values I typed.

I tried to find answers online but none of them fixed my problem. Is there anything wrong with my code?
Thanks!

```
Dim fish18(0 To 2) As String
fish18(0) = "$I$5"
fish18(1) = "$I$9"
fish18(2) = "$I$10"
```

Comment: The above code should work perfectly. Try putting a `Debug.Print fish18(0)` after the line which has `fish18(0) =`.  Also, make sure to put Option explicit on the first line of your code.  This will help to debug errors.

Answer (score 0):

> Check your values in the **Locals** window.
>   In VBE: View > Locals Window > Expand on Array (fish18)

```
Dim fish18(2) As String
  fish18(0) = "$I$5"
  fish18(1) = "$I$9"
  fish18(2) = "$I$10"
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the values in the watches window are still "".   :(

Comment: @Shry updated with photo. Please check the `Locals` window to see array values

Comment: It is really weird. I copied the exact code in my excel but there's still "" in the values. If I try to debug.print it prints what I wanted in the immediate window. I'm really confused.

Comment: btw I did exactly what you told me to do and still "" in the values in local

Comment: Do you have other code? Can you share you entire script?

Comment: That was very weird. Reopening excel somehow solved the problem. Thanks!